# Vpn connection not use default gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

Can I configure a VPN connection, such that after the VPN connect I can still use internet on local machine?

On Windows I can resolve this by unchecking the following box in ip config:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/I2Jkwj5aBU]

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old, but I wound up here recently while searching for the solution. For me, in Manjaro Plasma KDE there was an option in the "Routes" settings in the IPv4 tab of the VPN properties:

- Go to "Connections" in System Settings
- Select the VPN
- Go to the IPv4 tab
- click the "Routes..." button
- check the "Use only for resources on this connection" checkbox
- Hit "OK" then hit "Apply" then connect

[image]